# Why doesn't anything show up the body of this flutter scaffold?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The class in question is invoked from another page with the line

```
 onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        ProPage(iD: bestRatedPros[index]["ID"])));
                              },
```

Where bestRatedPros is a list of maps with the variable iD for the following class -

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProPage({Key key, this.iD}) : super(key: key);
  final iD;
  @override
  _ProPageState createState() => _ProPageState(iD);
}

class _ProPageState extends State<ProPage> {
  int iD;
  _ProPageState(this.iD);


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.white, //change your color here
          ),
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber
        ),
        body: 
           Text("EWFWEFEWEWFWEF",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))


    );
  }
}
```

The getDataFromBackend function and 
all the variables associated with it was meant to be within the body. But Nothing shows up in the body no matter what it is. Even a simple Text widget doesn't. I'm only trying to pass the variable iD from one page to the other without complicating things. The Run log doesn't show any Errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arun,

See below where your Text is:

[image]

Reason for that is that you specified:

```dart
extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
```

on your **Scaffold**, so body is expanded and top part of it is hidden behind **AppBar**